# asp.net WebAPI call not working from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin dosnt call anymore my api after i change the typ of Id from Int to string.
But that can't be the reason, before that it works without any problems

When I test the endpoint with Postman, everything works fine

When I debug it, the application runs through to response in the API call and then breaks off without an error message. No exception.

API Call

```
public async Task<bool> LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {

        _acc.UserName = username;
        _acc.Password = password;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_acc);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        **var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://192.168.178.41:45472/api/account/Login", content);**
```

//here is the break my Web API dosnt call.

```
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

My DI:

```
        public async Task LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {

        var result = await _accService.LoginUser(username, password);

        if (result)
        {
            await _navService.NavigateToAsync<Profile_ViewModel>();
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("nope", "nope", "nope");
        }
    }
```

My method in the ViewModel

```
        private async void GoLogin()
    {

        var container = ContainerConfig.CreateContainer();
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var GetService = scope.Resolve<IMyUser_Service>();

            await GetService.LoginUser(UserName, Password);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you running it in an emulator ?

Comment: What device/emulator OS versions are you using? i.e. You are using `http` so have you added non-secure exception handling for web requests?

Comment: are you sure the request isn't timing out?  have you verified that you can connect using the browser on the device?

Comment: cfun: yes i use a emulator
sushiHangover:  i use the default Emulator of VS19. Can u explane how i add it? 
Jason: i use Conveyor and if i install the cetificat iam able to start my request via device browser.. idk why but conveyor just show me the https Version of my localhost and not the http like before..any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Droid:
The AccessNetworkState permission is required.

Open the AssemblyInfo.cs file under the properties folder and add this:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState)]
```

Or update the Android Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

[image]

Xamarin.iOS:
App Transport Security enforces secure connections between the app's back-end server and your app. You can add the following code to your app's Info.plist file and It will disable the security defaults that ATS enforces for a given domain:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.178.41:45472</key> <!-- Your Domain address -->
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Or you can make the following changes to your app's Info.plist file to completely disable ATS for all domains and internet communication:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thx @Illnam but ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is enable. Still not works. 
I regonize if i start my API i get only the https version of Locoalhost and remoteURL. Before i get the http version too. Maybe it has a connection?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = null; 
response = await _accService.LoginUser(username, password);
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
 Console.WriteLine(response);
}

Comment: If you try this code and there is no content in the response, I think you should check your server code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the help until now. I make some checks and now i can say its my localhost what is broken. 
i get only https from conveyor but i need the http version because my app throw me the handshakeexception if i use https.

I try it with azure and now there throw me "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'" its the same code i only remove the using statement at GoLogin and replace the endpoint to my azure web service.

Still in postman works fine..

I am happy about help

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i solved my problem. My Model wasnt set right.