# Don't connect to web api in emulator but work in real phone in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create a xamarin cross platform project for receiving information from MVC web API,
in my android emulator project work for fine for 2 days and after 2 days when in debugging process , when debugger catch

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

skip from another codes without return any data and without any error,

this is my hole codes

```
 List<CompanyName> companyNameList = new List<CompanyName>();
        string url = Constants.RestUrl + "api/Companyname";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                companyNameList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyName>>(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR{0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return companyNameList;
```

In step one: I set SSL on my domain but problem is exist

In step two : I re-install windows and visual studio 2019 it work fine for 2 days but problem rise again,

after that with this situation I export my app and install in my real phone,
it work fine, why??
app not work on emulator but work in my phone with the same network.

Comment: Did you enable the internet permission in Android or app transport security in your iOS project? Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179094/13951772

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your firewall. if not please follow the below procedures.
Add an inbound firewall rule allowing access to the TCP port given in the Remote URL.

1. Open Windows 'Start' and type WF.msc.
2. Click 'Inbound Rules' on the left.
3. Click 'New Rules' on the right.
4. Choose 'Port' in the new dialog, then 'Next'.
5. Select TCP, and enter the port from the Remote URL next to 'Specific local ports'
   (45455-45500), then 'Next'.
6. Next, and next (you may want to disable 'Public'), give it a name like 'MyServer: web dev server access enabled'.